# Python Nvidia PyCUDA какую карту выбрать

Tags: python

Задача вычисления вычисления на PyCUDA (python)

Вот незнаю какую видео карту выбрать и на сколько критично количество ядер ?

Из бюджетных рекомендуют
NVidia Quadro 600  (Манагер говорит типа серия для вычислений) но там 192 ядра (10000руб)
а серия GeForce к примеру
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760  1152 ядра   стоит столько же 10000 руб

вот и вопрос что выбрать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите по ссылке http://versus.com/ru/nvidia-quadro-k600-vs-nvidia-geforce-gtx-760. После этого будет понятно, что второе скорее всего то, что Вам нужно, если цена устраивает.